# Why are 2 gamma photons created?

Tags: photons, electrons, momentum, conservation-laws, quantum-electrodynamics

When a positron and an electron come together they annihilate and produce 2 gamma photons
$$e^+ +e^- \rightarrow 2\gamma$$

I can understand that they must be produced in pairs to conserve momentum. However, that still leaves all other even numbers. Why 2 photons, why not 4,6, 8, 10... photons?

Note it is NOT a duplicate of [Why are two photons created in annihilation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/301658/why-are-two-photons-created-in-annihilation) because that question only asks how can mass-less particles have momentum.

Comment: You can get more than 2, it’s just less likely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positron-electron annihilation - can more than two photons be created?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216886/)